# Running Protractor Integration Tests on an Asp.net(C#) / AngularJS Project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, protractor, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 for a MVC-/angularJS -project.
I have written a couple of Integrationtests using the Protractor nuget package.

The problem is, I can only run these tests on deployed versions of the project.
Is there a way to run the Integrationtests against a freshly compiled version in running in debug-Mode on the same machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this blogpost will help you: [NUnit Unit Testing of ASP.NET Pages](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2011/12/22/asp-net-mvc-selenium-iisexpress).

AngularJS or not shouldn't make a difference with this guide.

Comment: Oh man, I just got done home-brewing something similar! Great find! Don't know if it solved the OPs problem, but it sure made my life easier!

Comment: AngularJS makes a difference, its pretty complicated to use logins that do not use angular but have to be handled before each tests.